# Maximized windows stop repaint when loosing focus

Tags: 11.04, unity, freeze

I have a very annoying problem.

When I maximize a window and than I change the focus to another window with alt+tab or by clicking it, when I go back to the first maximized window it stops to repaint. It means that window is still alive, i can understand it looking at the window title which is still changing but the only way i found to make the content window restart repainting itself is to detach it from maximize. At this point it works again.

I'm using ubuntu 11.04 with Unity with an ATI radeon HD4500 with propriertary drivers.

Answer (score 3):

Solved.

The problem was caused by compiz plugin. Specifically 'Apllication switcher' and 'Static application switcher' that need to be enabled without the use of mipmap to work properly with unity.

So if you encounter this problem just disasble mipmap in these plugins from ccsm interface.

Comment: Don't forget to accept your answer :) (Can usually take 2 days before you are allowed to.)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solve by removing the “mipmap” option from every Compiz plugin.

So check even the “Expo” plugin, since every time you click on the desktop selector you will make use of it.